# What is a "function lvalue" in the C++20. The standard mentions this term 5 times. But I couldn't find its definition

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

What is a function lvalue in the C++20. The standard mentions this term 5 times. But I couldn't find its definition.

Comment: function lvalue expression goes back to c++11...

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie to C++98

Comment: or maybe even to Bell C! But I think, I saw it in standard only in 2000s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply refers to an lvalue expression that has a function type, e.g. an id-expression naming a free function. Alternatively you can read it as an lvalue expression that refers to a function, which will have the exact same results when applied.

Comment: Could you give an example of a function id-expression being used in an expression?

Comment: @Ayrosa Every time you write the name of a (free) function in an expression: `void f() {} int main() { f; f(); &f; *f; auto p = f; }`. All mentions of `f` except in the declaration are id-expressions naming the function `f` and all are lvalue expressions of function type `void()`, i.e. function lvalues.

Comment: `f();` would be rvalue - a storable value or a `void`, `f` would be an lvalue (a "location"). The former results in fact that a function cannot be returned from a function - you must return pointer or reference

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `f` in `f()` is still an id-expression naming `f` and an lvalue expression. `f()` is indeed a prvalue expression.

Comment: @user17732522 In reference to your answer [link] to my comment above (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77503933/what-is-a-function-lvalue-in-the-c20-the-standard-mentions-this-term-5-time#comment136635415_77504014], I have to say that the spec doesn't say anything about what you wrote above. Not even something similar to that. How do you explain this? Do I have to guess?

Comment: @Ayrosa I think you are right that "_function lvalue_" isn't specifically defined anywhere to mean "_lvalue expression with function type_", but if there is no specific definition of a term you can apply usual English language interpretation. "X Y" is a X that is also a Y, and "_function_" here can either be interpreted as short for "_function type_" or as "_referring to a function_" with the same outcome. Which expressions refer to functions, have function type and are lvalue expressions is clearly specified for each kind of expression in the standard.